# Vb .net Concurrency violation

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I am using Devexpress Gridview to show data from a Mysql Database.

The data is loading correctly using:

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load    
 Me.GuardiansTableAdapter.Fill(Me.BusinessManagerDataSet.Guardians)
 End Sub
```

I can can commit any changes made via Grid to the database using:

```
Private Sub gridView1_RowUpdated(sender As Object, e As RowObjectEventArgs) Handles gridView1.RowUpdated
    Me.GuardiansTableAdapter.Update(Me.BusinessManagerDataSet.Guardians)
    Me.gridView1.RefreshData()
End Sub
```

However when I run the same code, replacing `Me.BusinessManagerDataSet.Guardians` with `me.BusinessManagerDataSet.Students` I get:

```
Additional information: Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records.
```

The project dataset has two tables (Students & Guardians) with associated datatable adapters.

Not sure if it is related or not, but when I view the tables in the Data Sources tab, some of the dates (sporadically) have a red circle with a horizontal line through them.

Any ideas?

Comment: Note, this is really more of a MySQL question than a Vb.net question.

Comment: Which part? The Concurrency violation, the Red Circle or both? Thanks @RBarryYoung

Comment: The whole question. Anyway, I have added the MySQL tag.

Comment: What is the update method on the adapter?  If this expects the Guardians data and you are passing the Students data, it can't find what it is looking for.

Comment: I have edited the TableAdapter and disabled `Use Optimistic Concurrency`  and all appears to be working as expected. However, I have a feeling this is just masking a deeper problem.